# How to configure a wireless router to point to a remote www proxy

Tags: wireless-networking, router, proxy, connection

I have a LG smart Tv with browser. I need the tv browser to connect to a uk based proxy server on port 808. Unfortunately there is no option within tv to setup proxy for its browser.

Now the Tv connects via a wireless connection to the internet. 
IE: TV <-> D-Link DIR-605L <-> ADSL <-> WWW.

Is it possible to setup this wireless router to connect the TV to the Proxy ??
If so ? where ? and what setings do i need to change in the wireless router ??

In short my question is ? 
How do i get the wireless router to make up for the lack of proxy connectivity within my Tv browser ??

Thanks in advance

NB: I have configured my Pc's browser's proxy settings, and streaming via the proxy works 100%

---

Thank you for your reply. I have had a look at the site you suggested. I really dont want to go down that route. I fully understand that the router I have may not offer the routing capability that I am look for. Seeing as I already have the Pc and associated browser solution.. I guess what I'm actually looking for is the physical hardware router solution that can replace the Proxy-ing capabilities of my Pc browser.

Moving forward If anyone can offer me the make/model of a suitable home router wired or wireless with associated settings to accomplish above I would be very grateful.

Once again thank you for your informative reply.

Answer (score 0):

Your router is not going to be able to carry out the quite extensive manipulation required to direct the connection to a proxy.

You might want to look at tunlr.com which does proxying without needing to configure a proxy server.  You set the tunlr DNS servers in your TV.  Any connection to a supported destination will be directed to their servers instead, and are transparently proxied via local server (in the UK if that's where the destination is).

Comment: See update by the OP.